# Dynamic width for report in ireport 4.0.1

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have designed a cross tab report in ireport4.0.1. because of cross tab i dont know the width for the report. Is there any option to set width according to the data it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my answer may not be the recommended one by jaspersoft guys,
but what i would do is calculate the required width at run time.

then put the value in the width option of the report that is in my JRXML which is basically nothing but an XML (using standard file operations).

Then i ll compile it to get jasper and fill the jasper as and when required.

To me this is the only option which is possible as of now.
PS: Alex is right u should consider accepting answers when they help you..!!!